# EC2 Window Instances - Paste Files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ec2-instance-connect

We have two EC2 Window instances. We had no issues copy a file from our local PC to the first EC2 instance. For some reason, we cannot complete the same function in the second EC2 instance. The paste option is grayed out when we attempt.

Both instances are created with the same role, security group, and subnet. The only difference between them is the AMI: the first (allows pasting) was launched as Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Base meanwhile the second is a CIS Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Benchmark - Level 1 (from AWS Marketplace).

Has anyone encountered this situation? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Issue has been resolved. CIS Benchmark level 1 2019 Windows Server has Do not allow drive redirection is set to "Enable".

Set to disable or not configured:

Start > Group policy >Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Device and Resource Redirection > Do not allow drive redirection is set to "Enable" .  Change this to "Not Configured"  This will allow your local C:drive to be mapped to the remote session.